# Match lines with possible preceding whitespaces

Tags: regex, emacs

In Emacs, I want to use regex to match lines such as

```
List of symbols
 List of symbols
   List of symbols
```

and not match lines which begin with a digit or `(` (with zero or more preceding white spaces) such as

```
1. Arithmetic and Algebra
 1. Arithmetic and Algebra
(a) Powers
 (a) Powers
```

But either `^ *[^[:digit:](]` or `^[[:space:]]*[^[:digit:](]` can match

```
 1. Arithmetic and Algebra
 (a) Powers
```

where there is a space at the beginning of each line.

I wonder where I am wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably reduce it to matching lines that *don't* start with a digit
or open parenthesis.

`^[^[:digit:](]`

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it happening?

Because of **backtracking!**

- Since `" "`(space) can occur `0 or more` times, it assumed `0` for the one starting with `space` and next character as `non digit` (which is the now a space). Hence it is matching the patterns with space at the beginning.

> How to overcome?

Use `*+` **(Greedy and Possesive)**.. which will make the `*` (greedy) `possessive` also

Working regex:

```
^ *+[^[:digit:](\s]
   ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pB6dW8/2)

Comment: Right now this regex will correctly match the first non-space symbol of the line, add `.*` after it to match the rest, unless i'm missing something language specific. Good answer though.

Comment: In emacs regex, `\s`  deosn't represent white space. `^ *+[^[:digit:](]` works the same as `^ *[^[:digit:](]`.

Comment: thanks. (1)  Both `^ *+[^[:digit:]([:space:]]` and `^ *[^[:digit:]([:space:]]` work. Why does  possessive not matter? (2) Does a regex without possessive always backtrack?

Comment: @Tim (1) thats because you included `space` in non match group.. (2) yes without possessive it will try to backtrack and match the pattern in any case.