# Does Emacs regex support possessive quantifiers?

Tags: regex, emacs

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30819146/3110638), which I found quite interesting. Can't test right now if Emacs supports [possessive quantifiers](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=P5UXAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA142&ots=HAiU71fgUp&dq=possessive%20quantifiers%20friedl%20mastering%20regular%20expressions&hl=de&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=possessive%20quantifiers%20friedl%20mastering%20regular%20expressions&f=false). The [manual says](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) that lazy quantifiers are supported:

> *?, +?, ?? are non-greedy variants of the operators above. The normal operators ‘*’, ‘+’, ‘?’ match as much as they can, as long as the overall regexp can still match. With a following ‘?’, they will match as little as possible...

But could not find anything about possessive [quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) like `?+`, `*+`, `++`

For example on string `ab`
`.*+a|b` [would match **b**](https://regex101.com/r/lR0pX5/1) but `.*a|b` [would match **a**](https://regex101.com/r/lR0pX5/2).

Are possessive quantifiers supported in Emacs regex flavor?

Comment: I think so? Seems odd to not support them

Comment: Possesive quantifiers are a Perl invention. Most engines that rip parts of Perl, have them, though usually cripple their aberration some other way. If Emacs only supports Posix flavoring then it probably won't support possessive quants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Emacs does not support `*+` etc.  See the Elisp manual, node [Regexp Special](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html).